# Saving High Frequency(100Hz) Sensor Data using performBackgroundTask in Core Data Lead to Data Loss and Crash the app?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-5

I am trying to develop a watchOS app that collects Sensor(accelerator) data at a very high frequency(100Hz). I am using Core Data to store the data and export it to a CSV file, then send to iPhone.

**The app crashed after a short time, because some thread's memory exceeded the limitation. And I also found out that the "performBackgroundTask" method creates too many threads and the CPU usage is more than 100%.**

**Another problem is when I fetch the data out, I got more data items than the that are actually stored in the Sqlite Database, which is quite confusing.**

Below is the code and the method is called in this method(`[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:self.queue withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion * _Nullable motion, NSError * _Nullable error) {}]`)'s callback block:

```
- (void)workoutManager:(nonnull id)manager didReceiveAccelerationData:(nonnull YLAcceleration *)acceleration {

    NSString *dateTime = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [self.coreDataStack.persistentContainer performBackgroundTask:^(NSManagedObjectContext * _Nonnull context) {
        Acceleration *accData = [[Acceleration alloc] initWithContext:context];
        accData.x = acceleration.xString;
        accData.y = acceleration.yString;
        accData.z = acceleration.zString;
        accData.heartRate = self.heartRate;
        accData.dateTime = dateTime;
        accData.session = self.currentSession;
        NSError *saveError = nil;
        [context save:&saveError];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Save data failed:%@", error);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Save data succeeded:%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
        }
    }];
```

}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Saving context with every data change is not the most performant way of doing it. You need to remove save context part out of this function and try again.

Comment: @BoranA Thank you. But where should I save the context? I mean the context will no longer exist once the block exits.

Comment: Why do you want to perform this action in the background thread and if you want to create a CSV file why don't you directly write it to the file and save it?

Comment: @BoranA Because the data are coming at a very high frequency if I save them on Main Thread it will block the UI. If I directly write the data to csv file I still need to find a way to handle the  high frequency data and deal with concurrency problems so I thought it might be simpler by utilizing Core Data. Thanks again.

Comment: It sounds like you’re calling `performBackgroundTask` faster than they can be performed. I’d suggest keeping track of whether the background task is finished or not, and if not, just append the values to an array. Then change the background task to save the pending array of values. Effectively, you want to decouple the saving from the frequency that new data points are coming in.

Comment: Summary of this conversation, data collection and writing to disk must be seperated. You can trigger the save for every 100 maybe.